# Error during favorite list feature (expected one thing, got another)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a to-do list, where I can have multiple lists with different tasks. My main problem is when I try to create a Favorite feature, where I can add lists into my favorite list.

List model

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :favorites

  has_many :favoriters, through: :favorites, foreign_key: :user_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Favorite model

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :list
 belongs_to :user
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and             :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :lists
  has_many :favorites

  has_many :favorite_lists, through: :favorites
end
```

Lists controller:

```
def favorites
 @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
 current_user.favorites << @list
 redirect_to lists_path, notice: 'Added to Favorite List'
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :lists do
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  post :favorites
end
```

Link_to at my show list view:

```
<%= link_to "Favorite", list_favorites_path(@list), method: :post %>
```

Message error:

```
Favorite(#70365311619800) expected, got #<List id: 1, user_id: 1, public: true, created_at: "2019-05-02 00:43:05", updated_at: "2019-05-02 00:43:05", title: "teste", favorite: nil> which is an instance of List(#70365317909860)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: I have a <%= link_to "Add to favorites", list_favorites_path(@list), method: :post %> in my list show view. I will edit my post and make sure I share this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe here:

```
def favorites
 @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
 current_user.favorites << @list
 redirect_to lists_path, notice: 'Added to Favorite List'
end
```

you want:

```
def favorites
 @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
 current_user.favorite_lists << @list
 redirect_to lists_path, notice: 'Added to Favorite List'
end
```

I believe you're also going to have to change `has_many :favorite_lists, through: :favorites`, here:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and             :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :lists
  has_many :favorites

  has_many :favorite_lists, through: :favorites
end
```

because `Favorite` doesn't have `favorite_list_id`, it has `list_id`. Something like:

```
has_many :favorite_lists, through: :favorites, source: :list
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked changing to .favorite_lists. Also I forgot the source: :list at my user model, becoming: 

    has_many :favorite_lists, through: :favorites, source: :list